# FabricJS - sendToBack not working as expected

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I've created a jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/r7omks2L/) where you can draw lines between 2 points (simply mouse down, drag and then mouse up to draw the line).

I've added

`inst.canvas.sendToBack(activeObj);`

within the mouse move function to send the current line behind the circle but it doesn't work until the next time you click the canvas.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I sent the circle to be moved backwards within the canvas, 'mouse:up' function

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
  circle.sendBackwards();
  canvas.discardActiveObject();
  canvas.requestRenderAll();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r0wbso6d/35/

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)

However, I need the line to be behind the circle during and after drawing it